# Puppeteer won't save screenshot headless Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a strange issue. I am testing my puppeteer headless on a Ubuntu server. I take a screenshot using:

```
await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
```

No error is thrown but when I check to see if the screenshot is there it doesn't exist. I have tested the same setup on headless via my local Mac machine and the screenshot does save.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Can puppeteer save screenshots on a Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen due to permissions issue, when saving a screen shot with a relative path, make sure the user running this code have `write` access to the directory you want the screenshot to be saved in.